# XML schema, why xs:group can't be child of xs:all?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256093(v=vs.110).aspx) (and my practice), `xs:group` element cannot be child of `xs:all`.
So something like

```
<xs:group name="g">
    <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:group>
<xs:all>
    <xs:group ref="g" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:all>
```

is not valid because group cannot be inside `xs:all`. But I want to define a schema, in which two elements (`first` and `last` in above example) both exist or neither of them exists, so I make them into a group. Then I want to make the group part of `xs:all` because the group can appear with other elements (for example, id element above) in any order. In other words, I want to have several elements are optional as a whole group. Without `xs:group` being able to be child of `xs:all`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can express both the "both or neither" _and_ "in any order" parts at the same time in XSD 1.0.  You could do it in 1.1 with an assertion on the parent.  Or have an explicit `<name>` element to contain the `first` and `last` of course, which might be clearer.

Comment: Also XSD 1.1 http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-all allows you to reference a `group` in an `all`, so first check whether you can not move to a parser that support XSD 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XML Schema 1.0 only permits](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-all) `xs:element` (and `xs:annotation`) under `xs:all`.

```
<all
  id = ID
  maxOccurs = 1 : 1
  minOccurs = (0 | 1) : 1
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?, element*)
</all>
```

It does not allow `xs:group`, `xs:sequence`, `xs:choice` etc.

[XML Schema 1.1 permits](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-all) `xs:element`, `xs:any`, or `xs:group` under `xs:all`:

```
<all
  id = ID
  maxOccurs = (0 | 1) : 1
  minOccurs = (0 | 1) : 1
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?, (element | any | group)*)
</all>
```

**Note**: Allowing unordered elements may sound ideal but rarely is truly needed.  Usually `xs:sequence` suffices in practice.

If you are willing to forgo the unordered requirement, you could (even in XSD 1.0) require `first` and `last` to "both exist or neither of them exist" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You are right. But I have to use XML Schema anyway.

Comment: *You are right. But I have to use XML Schema anyway*:   Are you saying you have to use XML Schema **1.0**?

Comment: Then I suggest that you abandon the unordered requirement.  Answer updated with an alternative idea that'll work in both XSD 1.0 and 1.1.